# Producing and consuming into to list using threads?

Tags: java, multithreading

I created two separate threads one for writing into a list and second for removing from the list.

```
package com.produ.consu;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Operations operations = new Operations();
        Runnable r1 = new ThreadsClass(operations);
        Runnable r2 = new ThreadsClass(operations);
        Thread t1 = new Thread(r1);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(r2);
        t1.setName("READ");
        t2.setName("WRITE");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

**Above is Test class where I created threads.**

```
package com.produ.consu;

public class ThreadsClass implements Runnable {

    Operations operations;

    ThreadsClass(Operations operations){
        this.operations=operations;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("WRITE")) {
            operations.writeList();
        }
        else {
            operations.readList();

        }
    }

}
```

**Above is class calling synchronized methods based on the thread name:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Operations {

    List<Integer> list=null;
    int count=0;    
    boolean flag;
    Operations(){
        list=new ArrayList<>();
        flag=true;
    }

    public  synchronized void writeList() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while(true) {

            if(flag) {
                count++;
                list.add(count);
                System.out.println("inise if block...."+Thread.currentThread().getName());
                System.out.println(list);
                flag=false;
                try {
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else {
                notify();
            }

        }
    }

    public synchronized void readList() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while(true) {
            if(!flag) {
                Integer i = list.remove(0);
                System.out.println(i+"..removed at index by"+Thread.currentThread().getName());
                flag=true;
                notify();
            }
            else {
                try {
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

**Above is where I mentioned functionality.**
So write thread hast to write element to list and wait until it is removed by the second thread.
Once removed second should notify 1st and wait for until element inserted.
But getting...

> *inise if block....WRITE [1]*

Not even removed and it has to be a continuous process.
Give me suggestions on given code.

Comment: I believe your problem is that two threads are trying to enter snychronized blocks. One of them manages to and waits for the other to also succeed. But the other thread cannot.

Comment: Take a look at the [Java concurrent classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) there you will find blocking queues that can help you implementing such functionality.

Comment: I have modified your code a bit, please check if it works.

Comment: yes it is working Amardeep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `wait()` inside the `else` block also, otherwise the `while` will continue to run if the `if` is not satisfied and the other thread won't get a chance to execute.

After the read/write operation is performed the thread should call `notify` to wake up the other thread and itself should go in the waiting state.

```
 public synchronized void writeList() {
      while (true) {
            if (flag) {
                count++;
                list.add(count);
                System.out.println("inise if block...." + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                System.out.println(list);
                flag = false;
                try {
                    notify(); //notify the read thread that write is complete
                    wait();   // go into the waiting state so that no further write is done until the current element is removed by the read thread.
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                try {
                    wait(); //wait in else, otherwise while will run endlessly
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
           }
      }
 }

 public synchronized void readList() {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("in read");
            if (!flag) {
                Integer i = list.remove(0);
                System.out.println(i + "..removed at index by" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                flag = true;
                try {
                    notify(); //notify write thread that read is complete
                    wait();   //go into wait until new element is inserted
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                try {
                    wait(); //wait in else otherwise while runs endlessly
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Amardeep and clarify me one more thing.lets say write thread first got a change so it entered and written to list.after that you called notify() so it given chance to read and goes to wait().Then why you  are calling wait() again.

Comment: @mae I called `wait` after the `notify` when the `if` is satisfied that is clear, but as the while is an infinite loop it may happen that `if` is not satisfied and it goes in the `else` block, in that case the while will loop infinitely and the thread which is executing will never give the opportunity to the other thread.So I need to tell the thread which is executing that you should stop and give the chance to the other thread as you have not satisfied the condition to run.

Comment: @mae you can verify this by putting a Sysout after the `while(true)` and commenting the `else` for both the threads, you would see that which ever thread is running, will keep on printing the Sysout. And please accept my answer if I made it clear to you.

Comment: wherever you call notify(),thread release the lock and goes to wait state right..?let say other thread call notify so again it get chance and execution starts from beginning then when wait() (you wrote after notify) get a chance to execute.May be these are basics questions but new to threading.Could you please explain me patiently

Comment: @mae *"wherever you call notify(),thread release the lock and goes to wait state right"* not really, the thread will release the lock only when `wait` is called after the `notify` and **then** go into the waiting state. So just before going into the waiting state I am notifying the other thread that the job is complete. So next time when it starts execution it will start with the `if` and not from `wait` .

Comment: One thread is waiting ,you called notify(), you mean othe thread do not start execution until you call wait()..?Then waht is the use just notifying.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188507/discussion-between-mae-and-amardeep-bhowmick).

Comment: @mae In this case as the method is `synchronized` on the `this` instance, the other  thread cannot start executing until the thread holding the lock is first released by calling `wait`.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the method synchronization with more granular synchronization: wrap the operations that access the list and update count with a synchronized block.

Alternatively, use a linked blocking queue to pass “messages” between threads (or, in more advanced scenarios, a messaging solution such as Akka, Kafka, zeromq, or other similar solutions)

Comment: What if i want to do with Synchronized methods.

Comment: The problem is that a synchronized method basically synchronized using “this”. So when your object is shared between threads only one thread may access a synchronized method at any given time. You could extract only the list manipulation part into synchronized methods and keep your wait notify logic out of the synchronized part.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only add one elemet at a time you could also use a Exchanger.
Take a look at the Java concurrent package.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.Exchanger;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Foo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        final Exchanger<Integer> exchanger = new Exchanger<>();    
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

        executorService.execute(() -> {
            // producer
            int count = 0;
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                try {
                    exchanger.exchange(count++);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }
        });

        executorService.execute(() -> {
            // reader
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("consume " + exchanger.exchange(null));
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }
        });

        System.in.read();

        executorService.shutdownNow();
        executorService.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        System.out.println("Shut down");
    }
}
```